# Page Renderer Navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have the CameraPage which is a Content Page in Xamarin Forms. For this CameraPage I have a PageRenderer called CameraPageRenderer for Xamarin.Android.

In CameraPageRenderer, I start a Fragment using

```
mActivity.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Add(Resource.Id.container, 
CameraFragment.NewInstance(this)).Commit();
```

The fragment provides a stream using Android's Camera2 API. On pressing the capture button, I want to navigate to the next Content Page but I keep running into some problems.

In my CameraPageRenderer I have the following method:

```
public void NavigateFilteredImagePage() {
            ((ImageDetection.CameraPage)Element).NavigateToFilterPage();
}
```

In my CameraPage I have:

```
public void NavigateToFilterPage()
{
            Navigation.PushAsync(new FilteredImagePage());
}
```

Once the image is saved, I call *NavigateFilteredImagePage()* from the camera fragment.

But I keep running into the following error,

```
Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x1 (unknown) for fragment FragmentContainer{f980387 #2 id=0x1}
```

Is there any way I could fix this, or is there any other way I can navigate from a PageRenderer to a ContentPage?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occured because I was using `SetContentView(...)` which messed up the MainPage. Xamarin.Forms only has one Activity for Android.

The OnLayout method in the PageRenderer should be overridden.